# How to force rescan of PCI bus (and reallocation of BARs) in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, pci, pci-express

I am developing hardware with a PCIe interface based on a FPGA. When I reprogram the FPGA, it looses its BAR settings (BAR0, BAR1, etc.). How can I force Windows to a) rescan the PCI (and therefore PCIe) bus and b) reassign the BAR settings.

This isn't a hardware issue; this is a Windows issue. It's roughly what one would need to to to hot-swap a card (if such is supported).

Edit 9/2/11: I'm not a software engineer, so I'm looking for something that can be done at the user level, including by administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I know drivers in Windows can be marked as "boot-time" wherein Windows won't allow you to uninstall and reinstall the driver.  If you changed the `pci.sys` driver to a different type, possibly you could uninstall and reinstall it from Device Manager.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a device in Device Manager will lead to re-detection after the next boot (if the device is still present) – boot time is the only time buses without hot removal are scanned.